# PLCrashReporter: Example iPhone Usage not works for iOS

Tags: ios, plcrashreporter

I just implemented PLCrashReporter, and artificially raised an crash, but **handleCrashReport** method is not called. Do you know why?

> NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"0"]; 
>   [a objectAtIndex:2];

Comment: Is Xcode debugger connected when you crash the app? Do you start the app again after it crashed? Crash reports are handled on the next startup only.

Answer (score -1):

I also thought this is problem, but all what you need to do is to get full crash, Not only application stop. It says that you need to click **Continue** button at XCode debugger until the device showing SpringBoard. then you need to start application again.

Good Luck.